# Couldn't connect to database when using Top Resource Consumers QueryStore Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-query-store, ssms-2017

We recently upgraded our SQL server to 2016 and I turned on QueryStore to do the analysis that it provides. I'm encountering a problem where, even if the time period of the report is Last hour, it will generate a message that says "Couldn't connect to database" even when running it on the database server itself. Sometimes if I keep refreshing the report it will eventually display some data, but it's intermittent at best. I'm running SSMS 17.5 on a sql server 2016 server.

We are having a somewhat similar issue with another program that connects to the database where it will sometimes not be able to connect, but every time I run my queries in SSMS, run reports in SSRS, or even use activity monitor, I never see any connection drops, so I'm not sure if it is related.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It works fine for me. I am also running SSMS 17.5 on 2016 and 2017 Server. Any luck with the error log?

Answer (score 0):

I find it works fine with the statistic set to Avg, StdDev, or Total. Max and Min give the error.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer rather it can be in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I found this happens when the query store runs out of space and gets into cleanup mode.

In database properties in SSMS try playing around with Query Store settings: for how many days it stores the query stats and does it get into "size cleanup" mode. More info on how to keep it adjusted: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#Configure